# Como hacer un condicional con mysql que me traiga un valor de acuerdo a un mes en especifico

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Esta es mi consulta en mysql:

```
select * from planeado where flota_plane='$meta' and fecha_plane='?'
```

En la tabla `planeado` se registra un valor y la fecha inicial de mes. ejemplo:

```
km_pane: 71548
fecha_plane: 2020-01-01
```

y tengo otro parámetro que ya me trae la fecha actual. Ejemplo:

```
$Variable = 2020-01-15
```

la idea es que en la primera consulta en donde la `fecha_plane='?'` es igual a esto `'?'` porque no se que poner allí para que me traiga la fecha que concuerde con el mes.

Si la variable:

`$Variable = 2020-01-15 //esa es igual al mes de enero`

y mi registro:

```
km_pane: 71548
fecha_plane: 2020-01-01
```

Esa tiene fecha del mes de enero sin importar el día pero que concuerde con el mes que me traiga el valor del `km_pane`.

De que forma podría hacerlo?

De acuerdo a las preguntas que me hacen abajo, tengo mi código completo de esta forma:

```
// de un formulario anterior viene un nro de registro y la fecha

$nro_registro = $_GET['flota_servde'];
$fecha = $_GET['fecha_desech'];

// entonces aquí hago mi consulta, le digo que me busque en la tabla: planeado 
el campo flota_plane donde sea igual a la variable que viene arriba por el GET
y de acuerdo a la fecha que viene por el GET me traiga la fecha_plane que corresponda con esa fecha.

$ok2=mysqli_query("select * from planeado where flota_plane='$nro_registro ' and fecha_plane='$fecha' ",$conexion);

$datos2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ok2);
```

Entonces la idea es que si $fecha es igual a 2020-01-15 quiere decir que es mes de enero.

Entonces en la consulta $ok2 le digo que me traiga fecha_plane='$fecha' solo me traera la fecha que sea igual, pero la fecha_plane no necesariamente es la misma.

La fecha_plane puede ser: 2020-01-01 la idea es que la consulta me traiga el dato de fecha_plane que corresponda al mismo mes.

no se si de esta forma se entiende mejor.

Comment: ¿No sabes cómo convertir `2020-01-15` en `2020-01-01`? No entiendo bien tu duda. Por cierto, si usas consultas preparadas, no concatenes cadenas con `$meta`.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código PHP que usas para hacer las consultas? Creo que el problema está ahí porque parece que no sabes usar consultas preparadas (lo de poner `?` y luego asignar a ese marcador un valor). Si compartes el código podremos adaptarlo para hacer el trabajo correctamente.

Comment: ¿Necesitas encontrar todos los registros cuya `fecha_plane` sea durante el año y mes dado?

Comment: @OscarGarcia realmente no está usando consultas preparadas (aunque debería). Curiosamente ha puesto el comodín `?` porque no sabe cómo filtrar por el mes.

Comment: Ya les voy a colocar todo el código.

Comment: Alli actualice mi pregunta al final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres filtrar por el mes necesitas:

1. Obtener el mes y el año desde la fecha que estás recibiendo
2. Usar `MONTH` y `YEAR` de MySQL para filtrar por el mes de la columna `fecha_plane`

Para obtener el mes hay varias formas, siempre es más seguro trabajar con objetos:

```
#Aquí $Variable es la cadena 2020-01-15 u otra
$mDate=new DateTime($Variable);
$mes=$mDate->format("m");
$year=$mDate->format("Y");
```

Ya que tenemos el mes, hacemos la consulta usando [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
$sql= "select * from planeado where flota_plane='$meta' and YEAR(fecha_plane)=$year AND MONTH(fecha_plane)=$mes";
```

---

Otra forma de hacerlo sería con `DATE_FORMAT`. Y es ahí donde vemos la bondad de los objetos:

```
#Aquí $Variable es la cadena 2020-01-15 u otra
$mDate=new DateTime($Variable);
$Ym=$mDate->format("Ym");

SELECT * from planeado where flota_plane='$meta' and DATE_FORMAT(test_date,'%Y%m') = '$Ym';
```

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Considera usar consultas preparadas, ya que la consulta ejecutada así
>   supone un grave riesgo de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano tu respuesta es muy util, pero tengo otra cosa que no se tomo en cuenta, debe tomar tambien el año, seria el año y el mes ya que tengo otros valores registrados con el mismo  mes pero en años anteriores.

Comment: ya logre hacerlo de la siguiente forma: extraje el mes tal cual como lo indicaste, luego extraje el año de igual forma solo cambie la letra m por Y $yDate=new DateTime($fch);
$annio=$yDate->format("Y"); luego declare una variable = $fecht = $annio.'-'.$mes; y en la consulta mysql coloque: select * from planeado where flota_plane='$meta' and date_format(fecha_plane, '%Y-%m')='$fecht' y ya funciono perfecto muchas gracias.

Comment: @estrada OK. Pero observa la respuesta. La ventaja de trabajar con objetos es única, puedes crear un formato `Ym` también con una sola llamada y usar `DATE_FORMAT` de MySQL o bien crear mes y año por separado y usar las funciones `MONTH` y  `YEAR` de MySQL.

Comment: entendido, muchas gracias por tus consejos y tambien sobre la seguridad que me comentas, lo tomare en cuenta, bendiciones para ti.

Comment: @estrada Gracias. Igualmente, bendiciones para ti. Saludos.